# C# Retrieve just the user accounts when displaying folder permissions and exclude system accounts

Tags: c#

I have a windows desktop application that gets the file access rules for a particular folder and displays them in a list box. The code is below. It displays everything, including system accounts (NTAuthority\System, NTAuthority\Local Server) with the individual user accounts (abc\mike.smith, abc\jan.jones). I'd like to filter out the system accounts and display only the user accounts. The user accounts are part of one domain, abc. Is there a way to do this? I'm using C#, but this is my attempt at working with Active Directory.

```
private void GetFolderPerms()
{
    Directory.Security dSecurity = Diectory.getAccessControl(@"C:\MyFolder");
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
    {
        lstPerms.Items.Add(rule.IdentityReference.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the items you add are a string, can you not just do a "Contains" before you add.

Comment: yes, sorry. that was a typo.

Comment: Either exclude the [well known sids](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) or just filter for the domain with string analyzation?

Comment: Using contains works. Thank you.